# Why does gcc -O1 affects std::rint()?

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, rounding

Why does the following code produce `-1` when compiled using `g++ -O1`? My gcc version is 13.2.1.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfenv>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    cout << rint(-1.6) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: testing on compiler explorer shows this happens on all versions of g++ on -On with n > 0.

Comment: add `-frounding-math` fixed the problem for gcc, [reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#:~:text=This%20is%20round%2Dto%2Dzero%20for%20all%20floating%20point%20to%20integer%20conversions%2C%20and%20round%2Dto%2Dnearest%20for%20all%20other%20arithmetic%20truncations.%20This%20option%20should%20be%20specified%20for%20programs%20that%20change%20the%20FP%20rounding%20mode%20dynamically%2C%20or%20that%20may%20be%20executed%20with%20a%20non%2Ddefault%20rounding%20mode)

Comment: @konchy Sounds like that's an answer - with some expansion and a (possible) indication that it is a non-conformance issue.

Comment: Also, try adding the `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` line, as mentioned on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For GCC, You should compile your program with `-frounding-math` if your program [may change the FP rounding mode dynamically, or may be executed with a non-default rounding mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#:%7E:text=This%20option%20should%20be%20specified%20for%20programs%20that%20change%20the%20FP%20rounding%20mode%20dynamically%2C%20or%20that%20may%20be%20executed%20with%20a%20non%2Ddefault%20rounding%20mode)

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mrc1YaPfr)